# How to dynamically manage azure devops users

Tags: azure-devops

Do you guys know how to dynamically manage (scripts, API, off-the-shelf solution...) the replacement of members coming from Azure AD with proprietary rights in Azure DevOps organizations and also in Azure DevOps projects (which are inside these organizations)

Thanks for your(s) answer(s)